# How to get specific number from table using selenium if location is static for every zip code?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, css-tables

Background Info: I want to web scrape a site using selenium in python since the site is in javascript.

Objective: retrieve a specific number from the table at 159x26

I thought this code would retrieve the text (aka number) at row 159 column 26.

This is my code:

```
word = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[159]/tr[26]').text
```

And this is the location of the specific cell at column 159 row 26

```
<td class = "size-11">46581</td> == $0
```

I want to collect the number 46,581

This is my error message:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//td[159]/tr[26]"}
```

Comment: Please post some more HTML code(may be for entire table) so that we can understand and help you better..

Answer (score 0):

1) Try using xpath = //tr[159]/td[26] 
tr's are rows and td's are columns. you are using td for rows and tr for columns

2) Another ways is first locate your table using id or xpath.
and on that element try to locate your element (in specific tr and td)

eg : tableElement = driver.findElement(By.id("tableid"));
element = tableElement.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[159][26]"));